# Calling Web Service from jQuery 1.9.2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am just trying to call the webservice from jQuery. My code is,

```
function SearchCandidates() {
$("#txtSearchGlobal").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {                    

            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert("ERROR:" + error.toString() + " " + status + " " + req);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {

    }
});
```

}

here, am getting an error saying `"ERROR : Internal Server Error error [object object]"`, am not able to find the exact error. I have worked with the same code mentioned above, so many times and I haven't found any issues in that. Am using jQuery 1.9.2 here, and I dont think the version is the problem. Can anyone help me here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> From your code remove the else from success and check and also place data type as **Jsonp** The below code may help you

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
url: url,
data: data,
 dataType: 'jsonp'
success: function(data){
 alert(data)
},
error:function(req, status, error){
 alert(JSON.stringify(error))
}   
});
```